# Two dimensional distribution

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $F$ be a two variable continous function that satisfy: if
 $x_1\leq x_2$ and $y_1\leq y_2$ then

\begin{equation}
F(x_2,y_2)-F(x_2,y_1)-F(x_1,y_2)+F(x_1,y_1)\geq 0.
\end{equation}
Define $p((x_1,x_2] \times(y_1,y_2])=F(x_2,y_2)-F(x_2,y_1)-F(x_1,y_2)+F(x_1,y_1).$ Prove that $p$ satisfy $p(\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n,b_n] \times (c_n,d_n])= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} p((a_n,b_n] \times (c_n,d_n])$).

Comment: Where are the things you tried to solve this question?